# Implement PowerShell DSC with existing continuous Deployment Process

Tags: powershell, deployment, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, dsc

I am doing PowerShell DSC POC. I configured the Pull server and one client machine. It is working fine and I am very much happy about PowerShell DSC feature.

Now I want to integrate this feature with our continuous Integration process. We are using Nolio for MSI deployment and do the other configurations. As of now I want to use DSC only for configurations and Nolio will continue for deployment process (due to reduce the Migration complexity). Later we planned to replace the Nolio with DSC including deployment. Here is my questions.

1)  We have monthly releases. As per my understanding I need to install the MSI(will deploy websites) in all machines including Pull Server and Nodes. Then I will do the configuration settings using Pull Server configuration. Once I configured the Pull server how could I do  the second deployment. Will Pull server node create any problem at the time of deployment like reverting the installed files as per old configurations? Is there any way to stop the Pull server settings at the time of deployment?

2)  If I want to install MSI also from DSC, I am planning to do that like below.

- Change the Pull server configuration to install the MSI from other configuration settings.
- Install the MSI in Pull server and all Node machines.
- Do all other configurations in Pull server.
- Change the configuration to apply pull server configurations to
  Node from Install MSI.

Is this good process?

Could you please anyone help me to achieve this? Please share if you have any other best practices.

Thanks in advance.